# Nextjs 13 dynamic route 404 not showing

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, app-router

I am working with Next.js 13, and I am trying to show a 404 page in a dynamic route when the id does not exist. This is my directory (I am using App Router):

/university/[id] -> page.tsx when I go to id 1 (exists) it shows the page with all the data, if I go to id 2 (does not exist) it shows the page without the data. Here I want to show the 404 page instead.

This is my code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

import ProfileInfo from "@/components/ProfileInfo";

type UniversityProps = {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
};

const University = ({ params }: UniversityProps) => {
  const [university, setUniversity] = useState({} as any);
  const { id } = params;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUniversity = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/profile/university/${id}`);
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setUniversity(data);
        } else {
          notFound();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    if (id) fetchUniversity();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      <ProfileInfo />
      <div className="py-8 max-w-7xl mx-auto">{university.name}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default University;
```

I am trying to use notFound() from next/navigation but I get an error in the console. I also tried using return { notFound: true, }

````
Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND
    at notFound (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found.js:23:19)
    at fetchUniversity (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/(profile)/universidad/[id]/page.tsx:26:78)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by using useSWR instead of fetch

```
"use client";

import useSWR from "swr";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

import ProfileInfo from "@/components/ProfileInfo";

type UniversityProps = {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
};

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

const University = ({ params }: UniversityProps) => {
  const {
    data: university,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useSWR<any>(`/api/profile/university/${params.id}`, fetcher);

  if (error) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <>
          <ProfileInfo />
          <div className="py-8 max-w-7xl mx-auto">{university.name}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default University;
```